# Plot multiple lines with `Manipulate`

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I have a function $e = f(w,a,i,\lambda)$. I first plotted the relationship between $e$ and $w$ for three different values of $a$ for given $i=0.1$ and $\lambda=0.5$. For this my code is:

```
e[w_] := (w + a (-1 - a w + w^2) - Sqrt[a (a - (-1 + a^2) (i + lambda) w + a (i + lambda) w^2)])/(w + a w (-a + w)) 
lambda = 0.5; i = 0.1; 
Plot[Evaluate@Table[e[w], {a, {0.1, 0.5, 0.9}}], {w, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, PlotLabels -> {"a=0.1", "a=0.5", "a=0.9"}]
```

which successfully generated the following:
[image]

Now I would like to vary $a = [0,1]$ and $\lambda =[0,1]$ using `Manipulate` to see how the above results would be affected. My code for this is:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
e[w_] := (w + a (-1 - a w + w^2) - Sqrt[a (a - (-1 + a^2) (i + lambda) w + a (i + lambda) w^2)])/(w + a w (-a + w))
Manipulate[ContourPlot[Evaluate@Table[e[w], {a, {0.1, 0.5, 0.9}}], {w, 0, 5}, {e, 0, 1}, FrameLabel -> {"w", "e"}], {{i, 0.1}, 0, 1}, {{lambda, 0.5}, 0, 1}]
```

which generates an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

The control variables in a `Manipulate` are local and if the function is defined external to the `Manipulate`, the control variables should be passed as explicit arguments to the function.

```
e[w_, i_, lambda_] := (w + a (-1 - a w + w^2) - 
    Sqrt[a (a - (-1 + a^2) (i + lambda) w + a (i + lambda) w^2)])/(w + 
    a w (-a + w))
```

Since the control variables define `i` and `lambda` you should continue to use `Plot` rather than switching to `ContourPlot`.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate@
   Table[e[w, i, lambda],
    {a, {0.1, 0.5, 0.9}}],
  {w, 0, 5},
  PlotRange -> {0, 1},
  AxesLabel -> {"w", "e"},
  PlotLabels -> {"a=0.1", "a=0.5", "a=0.9"}], {{i, 0.1}, 0, 1, 0.01, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{lambda, 0.5}, 0, 1, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much! This was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing Manipulate control variables, with the global variables used in your `e[w_]` function. One way around this is this. There are other ways.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
e[w_] := (w + a (-1 - a w + w^2) - 
     Sqrt[a (a - (-1 + a^2) (i + lambda) w + 
         a (i + lambda) w^2)])/(w + a w (-a + w));

Manipulate[Module[{data, w},
  data = Table[e[w] /. {i -> i0, lambda -> lambda0}, {a, {0.1, 0.5, 0.9}}];
  ContourPlot[data, {w, 0, 5}, {e, 0, 1}, FrameLabel -> {"w", "e"}]
  ],

 {{i0, 0.1, "i"}, 0, 1, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{lambda0, 0.5, "lambda"}, 0, 1, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {i0, lambda0}
 ]
```

[image]